# MP3 files suddenly don't play with kivy

Tags: python, audio, mp3, kivy

I have a game which, last time I checked, worked fine. The problem I have just today, for some reason I haven't figured out yet, kivy won't play mp3 files, but it will still play wavs. To reiterate, this was never a problem before now, the game ran on both my ubuntu linux os and android without a hitch EDIT: in fact, it still runs fine on my Android. I now get the following error on starting up the game on ubuntu:

```
File "/home/yerman/python/bird/gamescreens.py", line 107, in update
     point_play    = self.point.play
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

I also don't know why there is such a space between `point_play` and the `=` in the traceback as it's not like that in the file. I am quite sure that I haven't changed anything since my last time playing the game. There is nothing wrong with the mp3 file itself either. Converting the file to wav and using that instead works fine.

I then wrote this small script and ran it with the same results:

**main.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class PressMe(BoxLayout):

    sound = SoundLoader.load('point.mp3')

    def mycallback(self):
        self.sound.play()

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return PressMe()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

**kv file:**

```
#: kivy 1.8.0

<PressMe>:
    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        on_press: root.mycallback()
```

I really don't know why this isn't working, can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2):

When a loader returns a NoneType it usually means that the file could not be loaded by any available providers. On Android, MP3 support is provided natively, but for Ubuntu you need to have gstreamer. Exactly why it stopped working would probably depend on how you installed Kivy, but if you installed via pip or by building from the git repository, then the libraries on your system may have been updated.

Ensure that you have installed libgstreamer1.0-dev and rebuild Kivy (if installed from pip or git). If that doesn't help, then this issue would probably be easier to resolve on our [IRC channel #kivy on freenode](http://kivy.org/docs/contact.html#irc).

Answer (score 0):

This recomended for me..
Playying mp3 on terminal Linux (Ubuntu).
You can develop this optionaly.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mpg321
$ mpg321 yourmusic.mp3
```

But there are some things to consider when we use `mpg321`, namely:
Mp3 file name can not use a `space character` or `parentheses`.
Because not readable by mpg321.

Or Optionally again, use `pymedia`

Answer (score 0):

```
class PressMe(BoxLayout):

   self.sound = SoundLoader.load('point.mp3')

def mycallback(self):
    self.sound.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732454/unable-to-load-mp3-file-using-kivy-on-android):
Kivy only loads `.wav` and `.ogg` files on Android.

Also, sounds need to be loaded first in order to be played by Kivy sound player:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
sound = SoundLoader.load('point.wav')
sound.play()
```