# Unable to load MP3 file using kivy on Android

Tags: android, kivy, mp3, buildozer

I have created a music player using kivy. it is working fine for MP3 songs on Linux.
But when I am converting that into APK file using buildozer, then it is giving error that unable to load the file.
I am using sound loader of kivy to play the files.

This is working fine for .wav file and .ogg file. Error is coming only for MP3 files.

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Show the Code when you load the Mp3 files .. plus where do you place the Mp3 files...?

Comment: I have created buttons for each song and when I will press this button, it should play the song. Also it is working fine for .wav file and .ogg files.

Comment: I think we don't compile sdl2_audio with mp3 support, although it's probably straightforward to enable if you find the relevant patch in python-for-android.

Comment: Actually I am new on buildozer. So can you please tell me how to enable relevant patch in python-for-android.

Comment: Is this kivy sound loader problem or buildozer problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kivy only loads `wav` and `ogg` files on Android. Also make sure...

- You load the sound file with `kivy.core.audio.SoundLoader.load`
- You check `if <SOUND_FILE_VARIABLE>:` before you change the state of the sound because if the file doesn't exist or Kivy couldn't load the file, the sound file variable would be `None`

If the file is too long, the audio might be glitchy on Android.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using sound loader of kivy. But can you suggest any way to run MP3 file on Android using kivy. This MP3 files are working on my PC but when I am converting that into .APK using buildozer, this is not working.

Comment: There's no way to load `mp3` files using Kivy on Android. You can convert the `mp3` file into an `ogg` file though.